# Running time command with cron

Tags: cron, io-redirection, time

So I have a crontab that have this line:

```
30 16 * * * (time sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 run) 2>> ~/cpu.out
```

I use this because time output goes by default to stderr and I want to redirect it to a file

When I run the command in the terminal it does write the output I need:

```
real X.XXXs
user X.XXXs
sys  X.XXXs
```

But when I run with cron it writes this to the file:

```
39.69 user 0.92 system 0:40.67elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1400maxresident)k0inputs+1outputs (0major+450minor) pagefaults 0swaps
```

Can someone help me?

PS:
In the man page there is the -o option but it is not working, if I try that I get an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're running it in the shell, you're actually using the bash built-in function, which looks like this:

```
anthony@Zia:~$ time perl -e 'sleep 1'

real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Cron isn't using the bash built-in; it's using `/usr/bin/time`:

```
anthony@Zia:~$ /usr/bin/time perl -e 'sleep 1'
0.00user 0.00system 0:01.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1800maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+514minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

The second one actually has all the information from the bash built-in, plus more. It labels "real" as "elapsed". (This is also why the `-o` option is not working; that's an option for `/usr/bin/time`, not the bash built-in).

If you need to use the bash built-in, there are two things to try:

1. Put `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top of your crontab.
2. Change your command to explicitly call `bash -c "your command here"`.